Why i cannot initialize a reference to derived class without construction in base class?
I wrote the next code and if the comment line will be removed it will work. But i did the same with ref to int and everything was nice even without constructor.
#include <iostream>

struct B;

struct A
{
    B& b_;
    //A(B& b):b_(b){}
};


struct B:A
{
    int x = 5;

    B():A(*this)
    {
    }
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    std::cout<<b.b_.x<<std::endl;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/7hd7oaPon

Your program (both int version and class version) is derferencing an uninitialised reference. That is undefined behaviour. You get different behaviour from the two versions because that's what undefined behaviour means, the behaviour of your program is undefined. What did you expect to happen when you try to use uninitialised variables?

Note that adding -Werror -Wall will cause the compilation to fail with the appropriate error message.

@G.M. oh, thanks, i usually always use these flags but that case confused me)

with the constructor no errors...Why compiler doesn't optimize it? (i don't know how it's described in the standard)

A(*this) calls an implicitly declared copy constructor. You seem to expect it to be an aggregate initialization of b_ member, but that's not what happens. Whereas in the version with int& reference, the initialization cannot be interpreted as a copy constructor, and does initialize the reference member.

Why compiler doesn't optimize it?  What optimization level are you compiling with?

Generally you would't store a pointer/reference to the derived instance as it is a waste of space and it can be computed via a static_cast<B&>( *this ) - which is a no-op in most cases.
